# How to index Evernote notes with LaunchBar?

Tags: launchbar, evernote

I use both [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) and [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/), which are both great productivity tools.

I would like to have all my Evernote notes indexed by LaunchBar, so that I can access them by typing part of the note title and/or contents. For exemple, if I've got a `TODO list` note containing `Shopping`, I should be able to see my note listed by LaunchBar at least by typing "TODO" and possibly even by typing "Shopping" (although this latter part might be best handled by Spotlight).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this question and it made me go look for an answer! What I found is useful, though not directly addressing your question, it does provide the functionality. Perhaps someone coming here will find it useful as well.

**To Search Evernote from LaunchBar**

With LaunchBar 6.4 and Evernote 6.0.

- Fire up LaunchBar
- Call up Evernote by typing a few letters to select the app.
- Press Spacebar. A text box appears
- Type in some search text and press Return.

LaunchBar opens Evernote with a search in progress.

That is very slick for me.

Comment: Does it really work for you? In my case, Evernote opens up with the search keyword in the search box, but results do not change at all. Even pressing Enter does nothing to help. I have to literally go to the search box and play with the query myself, in order to activate it